# How to pass variables in the MySQL connection string in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a txt file which contains the log in credentials separated by newline. I want to pick up data from that file and set the connection string according to that. Here's the code for that.

```
$db = array(3);
$myFile = "sqlaccess.txt";  
$handle = fopen($myFile, 'r');  
if(!feof($handle))
{
    for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)  
    {  
         $db[$i] = fgets($handle);  
         echo $db[$i];  echo "<br>"; 
    }
}
else
{
     fclose($handle); 
}    
$dbhost = $db[0];
$dbuser = $db[1]; 
$dbpass = $db[2]; 
$dbname = $db[3];
```

the **echo** command displays everything correctly as saved in the file.
Now the connection string is:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass, $dbname);
```

This is not working. Connection fails

but connection is succesful if i hard code this as follows:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password', 'Newdb');
```

but hardcoding is not a good practice. so What could be going wrong in my code??

Comment: Sidenote: I hope you are using proper precautions to guard that text file. Plus, is there a particular reason as to why you would want to use such a method?

Comment: Have you made sure that $db has a value in every index referenced?

Comment: There should be `$db[$i] = trim(fgets($handle));`

Comment: You could just use `file()` which will return a file as an array, instead of all that extra fopen/for code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes I am encrypting that file and decrypting back for reading it. There's no perticular reason as to why I am using this method. I am just learning and trying these things in php.

Comment: @Anantvaibhav Ah, ok. I was only curious. It's not a usual method to use for logging into DB. *Cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fgets`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) will not strip `\n` from the returned string, so you either need to trim them yourself:

```
$db[$i] = trim(fgets($handle));
```

Or use the [`file`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function to replace your read loop:

```
$db = file('sqlaccess.txt');
```

If you choose the latter, your code is simplified to:

```
$myFile = 'sqlaccess.txt';
$db = file($myFile);

$dbhost = $db[0];
$dbuser = $db[1];
$dbpass = $db[2];
$dbname = $db[3];
```

Comment: @Sean Bright Thanks alot. I thot "\0" is causing trouble. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: Please don't encourage bad practices such as these in the future. While it's a useful answer, he's looking to do something and thinks this is how to do it.

Comment: @iWontStop I appreciate your concern. I am not doing this professionally. Its just for fun. Moreover reading the login credentials from a _".properties"_ file (instead of hard-coding the credentials as in your method) is a good practice I guess.  I will try your method also later. Its my learning phase man. CALM DOWN!